# SwiftUI View is not destroyed when window is bring as EnvironObject to the view

Tags: macos, swiftui, nswindow, observableobject

I have an app that has no startup window. So in my `@main` there is no windowGroup.

```swift
var body: some Scene {
#if os(macOS)
  Settings {
           
  }
#endif
}
```

But in app somewhere, It is needed to create a window. （Playground runnable)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

class AppWindow: NSWindow, ObservableObject {
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.hello)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hello = "Hello"
    
    init() {
        print("init")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

struct PlaygroundView: View {
    @State private var window: AppWindow? = nil

    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            createWindow()
        } label: {
            Text("open window")
        }
    }
    
    func createWindow() {
        if let curWindow = window {
            curWindow.close()
            window = nil
        }
        let window = AppWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView:
                                                            ContentView()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        )
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = true
        self.window = window
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(PlaygroundView())
```

everything is ok. The `ViewModel` will print the "init" or "deinit" when the window is being opened or closed.
Until in my `ContentView`, I want to do something like `setFrame(..` to the window.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var window: AppWindow // <--- added
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.hello)
    }
}
...
window.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView:
                                                            ContentView()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .environmentObject(window)  // <--- added
        )
...
```

The `deinit` will not be called when the window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about model data, the object that holds the model data is not usually supposed to be deinit during lifetime of the application. It usually is a singleton to safeguard against this and so we can still use data for previewing (`@StateObject` are not init for previews), e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(store.messages) { message in
            Text(message.text)
        }
    }
}

struct Message: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messages: [Message] = [Message(text: "Hello")]

    static void shared = Store()
    static void preview = Store(preview: true) // for previews
    
    init(preview: Bool = false) {
        if preview {
            // configure using sample data
        }
        print("init")
    }
    
    // methods for persisting/syncing model data
}
```

Use it like

```
ContentView().environmentObject(Store.shared)
```

And in previews like

```
ContentView().environmentObject(Store.preview)
```

If you are talking about view data, then it is simply:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var messages = [Message(text: "Hello")]
```

Pass it to a subview as a let if you need read access or mark it as @Binding if you need write access. SwiftUI will track the dependency and body will be called when the value of the let or the state/binding changes.

We don't use objects for view data because it would break SwiftUI's features like diffing and dependency tracking of state that rely on value semantics to work correctly and prevent consistency bugs. The View struct stores the data and the `@State`/`@Binding` property wrappers makes it behave like an object, that's your view model right there, if you made an actual object for this then it kinda defeats the purpose of SwiftUI and you would lose out on great features like automatic localization of `Text`.